# Pong Game - Ball Collision with Paddles?

Tags: python, pong, codeskulptor

Here is my collision code for the ball with the walls - Created in python(Codeskulptor)

The ball bounces off the bottom and top walls, and disappears from the left and right side if it is not hit by the paddle and reappears in the center to repeat

However, I cannot get the ball to hit the paddle and rebound - the paddle is a Circle object placed on the left of the screen (Height/2)

Any help would be appreciated

```
#Bottom and top walls
if Ballpos[1] >= (Height - Ballradius):
    Ballvel[1] = - Ballvel[1]
if Ballpos[1] <= (Ballradius):
    Ballvel[1] = - Ballvel[1]

if(Ballpos[0] <= 0):
    Score2 += 1
    Ball_Spawn(True)
elif(Ballpos[0] >= Width):
    Score1 += 1
    Ball_Spawn(False) 


#Update Position of Ball
Ballpos[0] += Ballvel[0]
Ballpos[1] += Ballvel[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's pretend your paddle has coordinates `Padpos` and radius `Padradius`. From your code, it looks like the coordinates represent the center of the circle, but you can make necessary adjustments if I'm wrong on that.

```
if (Ballpos[0] - Padpos[0])**2 + (Ballpos[1] - Padpos[1])**2 <= (Ballradius + Padradius)**2:
    # code for rebounding
```

Basically, just apply Pythagorean Theorem to see if the distance between their centers is closer than the sum of their radii.

Comment: FWIW, the `math` module has a [`hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.hypot) function that computes the Euclidean distance -- another name for the Pythagorean metric -- very quickly and could be used to both speed up and simplify your answer since you'd only need to compare the result to `Ballradius + Padradius`.